# How to update a specific table in APIATO without affect existing data added previously

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, apiato

I am currently working with apiato framework, as I already create tables and run migrate command, it will create a table but once I want to modify the existing table, therefor I need to run `php aristan migrate:fresh` which all the data of all the table will be deleted.
Do you have any other way which I can simply modify my migration code and update to database server without delete all existing data added?

Comment: I'm not familiar with laravel or apiato but I would be surprised if you could not ALTER a table given this is a mysql ddl option.

Comment: We have a migration file which we write each column of a table there like this

Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('customer_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('customer_email')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
so if later I modify this file for example create a new column, it won't affect my existing table

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid editing your old migrations file. Create a new migration and make your edits in there.

You can see how to update a table in [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#updating-tables)

Answer (score 0):

Editing a whole migration file especcially in production is not good.
better way to do this is create a new migration for you editing.
for example if you want to add a column in a table, create a migration called:

```
add_<column_name>_to_<table_name>_table
```

Having said that, migrate a single file wont change your whole db and just refresh a single file.
In order to that simply run :

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --path=<path_to_your_migration_file>
```

in you are using apiato, directory should be something like

```
Containers/<container_name>/Data/Migrations/<migration_file_name>
```

Hope that works for you.